# Outer SELECT takes the first result of the nested SELECT

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to get the courses where the last action (state) of the employee with the course is "enrolled"

This is the table of all courses

```
CREATE TABLE course (
    id integer primary key,
    name text
);
```

This is the table of all employees,
nid = NationalID

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id integer primary key,
    nid integer,
    name text
);
```

This a table where I record all actions of employees with all courses

```
CREATE TABLE tran (
    id integer primary key,
    nid integer,
    cid integer,
    state text
);
```

Here's my data

```
INSERT INTO course VALUES (1, "c1"); --> required result
INSERT INTO course VALUES (2, "c2");
INSERT INTO course VALUES (3, "c3"); --> required result

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (1, 111, "e1");
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (2, 222, "e2");
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (3, 333, "e3");

INSERT INTO tran VALUES (1, 111, 1, "enrolled"); --> latest action
INSERT INTO tran VALUES (3, 222, 3, "enrolled");
INSERT INTO tran VALUES (4, 222, 3, "rejected");
INSERT INTO tran VALUES (5, 111, 2, "enrolled");
INSERT INTO tran VALUES (6, 111, 2, "withdrawn");
INSERT INTO tran VALUES (7, 111, 3, "enrolled"); --> latest action
```

I'm supposed to get the rows I marked above

I can get the latest action with each course using this

```
SELECT cid FROM tran AS t1
WHERE t1.id = (
    SELECT MAX(t2.id) FROM tran AS t2
    WHERE t1.nid = 111
    AND t1.cid = t2.cid
)
AND t1.state = "enrolled";

Output: 
1
3
```

But when I try to wrap it with another SELECT statement to get the names of the courses, I only get the first one

```
SELECT id, name FROM course AS c
WHERE c.id = (
    SELECT cid FROM tran AS t1
    WHERE t1.id = (
        SELECT MAX(t2.id) FROM tran AS t2
        WHERE t1.nid = 111
        AND t1.cid = t2.cid
    )
    AND t1.state = "enrolled"
);

Output: 
1|c1
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please tag your question with the DBMS you actually use. Furthermore, textual values in SQL are typically surrounded with single quotes, not double quotes...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At first glance, you might try the `IN` operator.

```
SELECT id, name FROM course AS c
WHERE c.id IN (
    SELECT cid FROM tran AS t1
    WHERE t1.id = (
        SELECT MAX(t2.id) FROM tran AS t2
        WHERE t1.nid = 111
        AND t1.cid = t2.cid
    )
    AND t1.state = "enrolled"
);
```

Haven't tested it myself, however.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select t.nid, t.cid
from tran t
group by t.nid, t.cid
having max(t.id) = max(case when t.state = 'enrolled' then id end);
```

This returns employee/course combinations where the last id in `tran` is `'enrolled'`.

If you need additional information, you can `join` in the other tables.